# Adopting NSSecureCoding with opaque types

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, nscoding, xpc, nssecurecoding

I have an Objective-C class that needs to adopt `NSSecureCoding` for transport across an XPC connection. The class has a couple properties that are opaque types (`dispatch_queue_t` and `dispatch_group_t`).

How would I go about implementing `-initWithCoder:` and `-encodeWithCoder:` in this case? The documentation says that these are object-like structures so I'm assuming they would need to be converted to/from raw bytes when encoding/decoding? If this is the case, I'm not sure which methods should be used to do this. Another option would be to simply avoid encoding them at all and recreate them inside `-initWithCoder:`.

Comment: You answered your own question. They're opaque types, so you cannot encode them and decode them later. You would have to recreate them in `-initWithCoder:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a general solution for *all* opaque types, but you mentioned `dispatch_queue_t` and `dispatch_group_t`.  If the dispatch queue and group are private to the coded object, then just recreate them in `-initWithCoder:` like Kurt Revis said. If they're shared, it is a little bit more hairy, but you can sometimes work around it by archiving a "surrogate" object, then traversing your object graph after decoding it, replacing all references to the surrogate with references to a single, newly-created "real" object.

Really though, this sounds suspiciously like an anti-pattern. Classes that implement NSCoding/NSSecureCoding would typically be model classes, and it's kind of a red flag that there are dispatch queues and groups in ivars of a model class. I can think of *some* legitimate reasons to have a private queue (i.e. serializing multithreaded access to internal state) in a model class ivar, but not a shared one. In general, it sounds like some re-factoring might be in order.